# Convert from Long to date format

Tags: android, date, long-integer

I want to convert Long value to String or Date in this format dd/mm/YYYY.

I have this value in Long format: 1343805819061.

It is possible to convert it to Date format?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

You can use below line of code to do this. Here timeInMilliSecond is long value.

```
 String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(new Date(TimeinMilliSeccond));
```

Or you can use below code too also.

```
 String longV = "1343805819061";
 long millisecond = Long.parseLong(longV);
 // or you already have long value of date, use this instead of milliseconds variable.
 String dateString = DateFormat.format("MM/dd/yyyy", new Date(millisecond)).toString();
```

Reference:- [DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html) and [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

P.S. Change date format according to your need.

Comment: Just to add, if you are also getting some 1970 date from it, please ensure your timestamp is in miliseconds. A datetimestamp of recent years should have 13 digits in it. I was struggling a lot with this as mine had 10 digits.

Answer (score 5):

You can use method setTime on the Date instance or the contructor Date(long);

```
setTime(long time) 
      Sets this Date object to represent a point in time that is time milliseconds after January 1, 1970 00:00:00 GMT.

Date(long date) 
      Allocates a Date object and initializes it to represent the specified number of milliseconds since the standard base time known as "the epoch", namely January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT
```

Then use the simple date formater

see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/text/DateFormatter.html

Answer (score 4):

```
java.util.Date dateObj = new java.util.Date(timeStamp);
```

Here **timeStamp** is your long integer which is actually timestamp in millieseconds,
you get the java date object, now you can convert it into string by this

```
SimpleDateFormat dateformatYYYYMMDD = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
SimpleDateFormat dateformatMMDDYYYY = new SimpleDateFormat("MMddyyyy");

StringBuilder nowYYYYMMDD = new StringBuilder( dateformatYYYYMMDD.format( dateObj ) );
StringBuilder nowMMDDYYYY = new StringBuilder( dateformatMMDDYYYY.format( dateObj ) );
```

Answer (score 3):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

I am providing the modern answer. I suggest using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work. This will work on your Android version:

```
    // Take Catalan locale as an example for the demonstration
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter
            = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.MEDIUM)
                    .withLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("ca"));

    long millisecondsSinceEpoch = 1_343_805_819_061L;
    ZonedDateTime dateTime = Instant.ofEpochMilli(millisecondsSinceEpoch)
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    String dateString = dateTime.format(dateFormatter);
    System.out.println("As formatted date: " + dateString);
```

Output is:

> As formatted date: 01/08/2012

I recommend that you use a built-in localized date format for presentation to your user. I took Catalan date format just as an example. Formats for many languages, countries and dialects are built-in.

The `SimpleDateFormat` class used in most of the old answers is a notorious troublemaker of a class. The `Date` class also used is poorly designed too. Fortunately they are both long outdated. It’s no longer recommended to use any of those. And I just find java.time so much nicer to work with.

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On (older) Android use the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. And make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Answer (score 1):

if thre is 10 digits in long then try this

long DateInLong= 1584212400;

Date date = new Date(DateInLong*1000L);

SimpleDateFormat simpledateformate= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

String DATE = simpledateformate.format(date);

Answer (score 0):

```
    public String getDuration(long msec) {
        if (msec == 0)
            return "00:00";
        long sec = msec / 1000;
        long min = sec / 60;
        sec = sec % 60;
        String minstr = min + "";
        String secstr = sec + "";
        if (min < 10)
            minstr = "0" + min;
        if (sec < 10)
            secstr = "0" + sec;
        return minstr + ":" + secstr;
    }
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.